# Split Columns in a List of Dataframes R

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames which some columns have this special character **->**(arrow). Now i do want to loop through this list of data frames and locate columns with  this **->** (arrow) then the new columns be named with a suffix _old and _new. This is a sample of data frames :

```
dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("reg->joy", "ress", "mer->dls"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("me", "df", "kl"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane->dlt", "Egg"),
                      t3 = c("James ->may","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
dput(df3)
df3 <- structure(list(v1 = c("56->34", "df23-> ", "mkl"),
                      t2 = c("James","Jane", "Egg"),
                      d3 = c("James->","Jane", "Egg")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

This is what I have tried

```
dfs <- list(df1,df2,df3)

for (y in 1:length(dfs)){
  setDT(dfs[[y]])
  df1<- lapply(names(dfs[[y]]), function(x) {
    mDT <- df2[[y]][, tstrsplit(get(x), " *-> *")]
    if (ncol(mDT) == 2L) setnames(mDT, paste0(x, c("_old", "_new")))
  }) %>% as.data.table()

}
```

This only splits one data frame, I need to split all of the data frames.
**NOTE:** The code I have splits so well on one dataframe, what I want is how to implement it on a List of data frames

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(v1_old = c("reg", "mer"),
                      v1_new = c("joy", "dls")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(t2_old = c("dlt"),
                      t2_new = c("dlt"),
                      t3_old = c("James"),
                      t3_new = c("may")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))

dput(df3)
df3 <- structure(list(v1_old = c("56", "df23 "),
                      v1_new = c("34", " "),
                      d3 = c("James"),
                      d3 = c(" ")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Comment: Have you tried rewritting your code as a function that you could use with lapply on  a list of dataframes?

Comment: @Fnguyen not really how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

I add below a solution using the tidyverse.

Select the columns if one of the strings in the columns contains an arrow:

```
col_arrow_ls <- purrr::map(dfs, ~select_if(., ~any(str_detect(., "->"))))
```

Then split the function using tidyr::separate. Since each element of the output is a data frame, purrr::map_dfc is used to column-bind them together:

```
split_df_fn <- function(df1){
  names(df1) %>%
    map_dfc(~ df1 %>% 
               select(.x) %>% 
               tidyr::separate(.x, 
                               into = paste0(.x, c("_old", "_new")), 
                               sep = "->")
    )
}
```

Apply the function to the list of data frames.

```
purrr::map(col_arrow_ls, split_df_fn)

[[1]]
  v1_old v1_new
1    reg    joy
2   ress   <NA>
3    mer    dls

[[2]]
  t2_old t2_new t3_old t3_new
1  James   <NA> James     may
2   Jane    dlt   Jane   <NA>
3    Egg   <NA>    Egg   <NA>

[[3]]
  v1_old v1_new d3_old d3_new
1     56     34  James       
2   df23          Jane   <NA>
3    mkl   <NA>    Egg   <NA>
```

Comment: I am getting this error on large list of dataframes Error in eval_tidy(quo, mask) : '...' used in an incorrect context

Comment: @LivingstoneM You should first check whether your column names are valid. See: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/name-repair-retired.html

Comment: am unable to remove the error. my column names are valid

Comment: Try to apply the above code on different subsets of your data frames in the list.